# Using wildcard in WebDriver By.XPATH

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, wildcard

Researching on Google I was lead to beleive that you could use * as wildcard in XPATH statements but that seems not to be the case. Therefor could anybody help me find a good XPATH statement for the following case:

I have X number of input fields with a id pattern of "optionsX.name".
X can be any number but will likely be between 0-99, so could be 2 digits.
Like:

```
<input id="options0.name" type="text" value="value" name="options[0].name">
```

How do I make a XPATH statement that returns ALL input elements matching that pattern?
I tried the before mentioned wildcard like this:

```
int numberOfFields = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='options*.name']")).size();
```

With the used XPATH being:

```
//input[@id='options*.name']
```

I would like a statement that only returns inputs with id excatly 'options??.name' where ?? can be one or two digit wildcard/unknown, as there's other similar input with other endings I do not want included. So I need both the prefix and suffix around the wildcard.

Regards Martin

Answer (score 2):

## Regular Expressions with XPath 2.0

You cannot use wildcards in string comparisons. In XPath 2.0 (which is not supported by selenium) you could use `fn:matches(...)` which matches against regular expressions:

```
//input[matches(@id, 'options\d+\.name')]
```

## Simulating Wildcards in XPath 1.0

In XPath 1.0, all you can do is check the start and end of the string against a pattern (which actually is the same like having a wildcard in between). Sadly, while there is `starts-with(...)`, `ends-with(...)` is only available starting with XPath 2.0, so we will have to work around that:

```
//input[starts-with(@id, 'options') and contains(substring(@id, string-length(.)-4), '.name')
```

It is not possible to construct multiple wildcards in one string using that pattern.

Comment: Thx. I ended up doing this before I saw yours: "//input[starts-with(@id, 'options') and contains(@id,'.name')]" but not as precise as yours. Could you explain what substring(@id, 4) does in your method? Snips out the 4 first chars of ID? Because that wouldn't fit pattern as I need to look at the last 5 chars for ".name".

Comment: Aye, that should have been `string-length(.)-4`. We want the _last 5 digits_, not everything from the 4th character. Fixed that flaw.